# Por que bota Error en BD mysql al hacer una insercion directamente

Tags: base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Intento insertar un registro directamente en la BD mysql,la tabla se llama acceso pero al dar clic en insertar dice que hay un error,sin embargo intente hacer la inserción pero no pude hacerla,osea el error está antes de hacer la inserción,dice que hay un error cerca del VALUES.Apenas estoy iniciando en esto,agradezco su paciencia,esta tabla tiene una llave primaria acce_id y  una llave heredada llamada empl_doc.[image: foto de la BD]

Comment: si trabajas con BD en MySQL podrias intentar tambien con esta sintaxis
insert into Nombre_tabla values('valor1','valor2','valor3')

Comment: es mejor no suponer y esperar a que el OP indique mejor su pregunta

Comment: El indica que trabaja con eso por ende propuse una sintaxis la cual ya he trabajado y se que funciona

Comment: Hola Pia, por favor Edita la pregunta para añadir el código con el que estás teniendo problemas. Solo con la captura no es suficiente. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: por favor agrega la sentencia SQL que estas tratando de hacer, el error es un complemento pero no entrega todos los datos que hacen falta para ayudarte

Comment: no deberás utilizar los símbolos de los corchetes, es decir si vas a guardar un número entero solo iría así: 2, si vas a guardar una cadena de texto solo va entre comillas

Comment: Ya lo habia intentado pero  no funciono,creo que el error se debe a que  tiene una llave secundaria

Comment: no @Pia el error es de sintaxis, si editas y explicas que tipo de dato tiene cada una seguro se identifica mas rapido el problema

Comment: Parece que estás usando notación de MSSQL/SQL Server para una consulta en MySQL.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda,volvi a intentar pero corregi los  datos de otra tabla de donde venia  la  llave foranea,despues lo intente otra vez en la tabla acceso asi  como dijeron sin comillas y al fin dejo insertar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejemplos de insert:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidos) VALUES ('Juan','Garcia Pérez');
```

Prueba Borrando loscaracteres [] en la parte de values.

values ('','')